# Calculate the inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Calculate the inner product:
$\langle\,\vec v$,$A^{99}\vec v\,\rangle$ where $\vec v = (1,0)$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 18 & -12\\ 20 & -13 \end{pmatrix} $

If it is $A$ instead of $A^{99}$, the answer is $18$.
It is hard for me to develop a formula to know what the matrix will be after $98$ times of multiplication. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: Hint: Try multiplying $A$ by itself a couple of times to see if you get a nice pattern from it..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** That inner product will be equal to the $(1,1)$ entry of $A^{99}$.  We can compute this by diagonalizing $A$, i.e. noting that $A = SDS^{-1}$ with
$$
D = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&3}, \quad S = \pmatrix{3&4\\4&5}.
$$

---

Another approach that I find interesting: let $c_n = \langle v, A^n v\rangle$ (where we define $A^0 = I$).  After computing the characteristic polynomial, we can state by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem that $A^2 - 5A + 6I = 0$.  Thus, for any $n \geq 2$ we have
$$
A^{n} = A^{n-2}(A^2) = A^{n-2}(5A - 6I) = 5A^{n-1} - 6A^{n-2}.
$$
It follows that for any $n \geq 2$,
$$
c_n = \langle v, A^n v \rangle = 
\langle v, (5A^{n-1} - 6A^{n-2})v\rangle \\
= 5 \langle v, A^{n-1}v \rangle - 6 \langle v, A^{n-2} \rangle\\
= 5c_{n-1} - 6c_{n-2}.
$$
That is: our question can be restated as asking for $c_{99}$ where the sequence $(c_n)$ satisfies the [linear recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation#Solution_of_homogeneous_case)
$$
c_n = 5c_{n-1} - 6c_{n-2} \quad n \geq 2,\\
c_0 = 1, \quad c_1 = 18.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\vec{x}M\vec{x}$ is always the first entry of $M$ when $\vec{x}=(1,0)$

Try calculating some powers of $A$, like $A^2$, $A^3$ and so on.... Can you see a pattern?

Once you've figured out, try to prove by induction that it holds for every $n=1,2,3...$

Finally, use the "formula" for the case $n=99$

Comment: The formula 
$$
A^n = \pmatrix{-15 \cdot 2^n + 16 \cdot 3^n & 12 (2^n - 3^n)\\
-20 (2^n - 3^n) & 2^{n + 4} - 5 \cdot 3^{n + 1}}
$$
doesn't seem like the kind of formula that is easy to "guess" by looking at the first few values of $n$.  The best I think you could do is "notice" that each of the entries satisfies the recurrence
$$
c_n = 5c_{n-1} - 6c_{n-2}
$$